# Finding every first array in nested array

Tags: javascript, arrays, node.js, turfjs

I have a function that sometimes generates a nested array (for multiPolygon purposes). It could look like this:

```
[
  [
    [ 10.0, 59.0],
    [ 10.0, 59.0],
    [ 10.0, 59.0]
  ],
  [
    [ 10.0, 59.0],
    [ 10.0, 59.0],
    [ 10.0, 59.0]
  ]
]
```

So it could return a nested array with multiple nested arrays inside. But i want to make shure that i only get the first nested array, like this:

```
[
  [
    [ 10.0, 59.0],
    [ 10.0, 59.0],
    [ 10.0, 59.0]
  ]
]
```

Im developing in NodeJS.

Comment: so return only one nested array in the function you have? What did you try so far?

Comment: I did it like this now, and this worked for my case:
while(Array.isArray(nestedArray[0][0])) { nestedArray = nestedArray[0]; }

Comment: actually all you had to do was this: `originalArray.length = 1;`

Comment: `originalArray.length = 1;` will truncate `originalArray.length` in such a way that only the first element remains.

Comment: @IgweKalu wow! That actually worked. But i dont understand how it works. Does it truncate all the nested arrays, no matter how many?

Comment: Let me explain, assuming you have an array defined as follows `var arr = ["one", "two", "three", "four"];`, if you want to reduce it to contain only the first two elements, all you have to do is `arr.length = 2;` and the result will be `["one", "two"]`. I hope it's clear for you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A simple recurrence function which looks for another arrays solves it. It works with infinitely nested arrays and use object type protection.

```
function getFirstArray(array){
  var hasArrays = false;
  for (i in array) {
    if(typeof(array[i]) == "object"){
      return getFirstArray(array[i]);
      hasArrays = true;
      break;
    }
  }
  if(!(hasArrays)){
    return array;
  }
}
```

Then use it simply as:

```
var firstArray = getFirstArray(matrix);
console.log(firstArray);
```

Hope this helps :)

Answer (score 0):

Loop through the arrays, and then output yourArray[0] to output the first element. I believe that should work.

Comment: But how do i loop through a nested array when i dont know how many nested arrays there are?

Comment: It's called recurrency function, check my full answer.

Answer (score 0):

I would try something like this (js console is acting ill, so I can't test):

```
var first = function(a){
    return a[1]
}

var deepFirst = function(a, depth) {
    depth = depth || 0
    if (a.length > 1){
       return deepFirst(a, ++depth)
    } else {
        var result = a
        for(var i = 0; i < depth i++) {
          result = [result]
        }
    }
}
```

There are no type or safety checks, and I would probably replace the for loop with something recursive as well...